# Detached deck on a steep slope

Tags: deck

I have a Lake House.
Small but functional backyard about 12' above lake level.  Slopes steeply to the Lake starting at about 20 feet from the house.  I want to add more sqft to the functionality of the back yard.
Would like to build a deck on piers about 30 wide x 20 deep detached from the house and starting where the grade starts to drop off.

I would like edge of the deck on the house side to blend seamlessly with the grass in the backyard (at grade basically).  What construction techniques can be used to pull this off?

Comment: Also house is in Western NY.  36" frost line.

Comment: Welcome. First, all information belongs in your post, not down here in comments. Then, your question is quite broad. Please take the [tour] and see https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to be more specific.

Comment: The short answer is that footings don't care about the slope. You'd just build a deck as normal with posts of the appropriate length. You'll want to talk to your local inspection office about lake setbacks. From your description you'd need footings practically at the lake edge. That's likely not allowed.

Comment: That close to the lake you might need to drive piles, rather than use traditional footings...

Answer (score 1):

In terms of blending into the grass I recommend a combination of a small retaining wall and a 2' cantilever (overhang). This way the foundation for your deck can be two feet back from the seamless edge and the retaining wall can keep the soil back from the deck.

Another option would be to put a ledger board on the retaining wall. If you do that make very sure that your retaining wall has the proper foundation for the slope and the load that the deck will add (as a fellow DIY'er I would hire a pro for this and do the deck myself).

Sounds like a wonderful addition. Have you thought about how you will get down to the water. You could add a floating dock with a ladder / stairs / ramp to the deck. This might also help if you can't get as close to the water as you would like due to setbacks etc.

Jonathan